# git send-email fail to send message

Tags: git, smtp, sendmail, smtpclient, git-send-email

I am trying to send a git patch for a upstream community review; But the receiver does not receive the message;

I have tried changing '`--to`' to one of my private email-id, but even this is not being received at my private mailbox;

command:

```
git send-email --no-chain-reply-to --from "Ganapathi Bhat <xxx@gmail.com>" --to linux-wireless@vger.kernel.org my_patch.patch
```

output:

```
Unable to initialize SMTP properly. Check config and use --smtp-debug. VALUES: server=smtp.gmail.com encryption=tls hello=yyy.yyy.com port=587 at /usr/lib/git-core/git-send-email line 1506
```

command:

`git config -l`

output:

```
user.email=xxx@gmail.com
user.name=Ganapathi Bhat
sendemail.smtpencryption=tls
sendemail.smtpserver=smtp.gmail.com
sendemail.smtpuser=xxx@gmail.com
sendemail.smtpserverport=587
```

The patch should get delivered to the community for review process and it should appear in below list:
https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-wireless/list/

Comment: Can you run the command with `--smtp-debug` and edit your reply to contain the output it produces?

Comment: I did not get any extra verbose after adding `--smtp-debug=1`; Even `tcpdump` does not show anything;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering [`git send-email` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email#Documentation/git-send-email.txt---toltaddressgt82308203), test if adding an equal ('`=`') changes anything:

```
git send-email --no-chain-reply-to --from="Ganapathi Bhat" --to=linux-wireless@vger.kernel.org my_patch.patch
                                        ^^^                   ^^^
```

The next step is to check your [sendemail config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-sendemailidentity): `git config -l`
See [Git Tips](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitTips#Mail).
For example, with GMail:

`git send-email` now supports TSL/SSL, so using gmail is as simple as setting the following configuration variables:

```
[sendemail]
    smtpencryption = tls
    smtpserver = smtp.gmail.com
    smtpuser = yourname@gmail.com
    smtpserverport = 587
```

The [OP Ganapathi Bhat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6431834/ganapathi-bhat) confirm a configuration issue [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56421262/git-send-email-fail-to-send-message/56421328?noredirect=1#comment103906281_56421328):

> [git send-email fail to send message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56421262/git-send-email-fail-to-send-message/56421328?noredirect=1#comment103906281_56421328)
>
> I was using wrong "smtpserver";
> I contacted the IT person, got the correct "smtpserver" to be used, which fixed the issue.

---

Speaking of `sendmail` config, make sure to use `sendemail`!

Git 2.29 (Q4 2020) will stop when "`sendmail.*`" configuration variables are defined, which could be a mistaken attempt to define "`sendemail.*`" variables.

See [commit dd84e52](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd84e528a34c3822e7ab0473a95e411665b37681) (23 Jul 2020) by [Drew DeVault (`ddevault`)](https://github.com/ddevault).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a00bda2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a00bda2b2fa5e6a8b224734cf72bb0601cd65b8a), 17 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`git-send-email`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd84e528a34c3822e7ab0473a95e411665b37681): die if `sendmail.*` config is set
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Drew DeVault</sup>

> I've seen several people mis-configure [`git send-email`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/dd84e528a34c3822e7ab0473a95e411665b37681/Documentation/git-send-email.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email))</sup> on their first attempt because they set the `sendmail.*` config options - not `sendemail.*`.
> This patch detects this mistake and bails out with a friendly warning.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/dd84e528a34c3822e7ab0473a95e411665b37681/Documentation/config/sendemail.txt#L64-L68):

> ### `sendemail.forbidSendmailVariables`
>
> To avoid common misconfiguration mistakes, `git send-email`
> will abort with a warning if any configuration options for "`sendmail`"
> exist. Set this variable to bypass the check.

---

With Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), "[`git send-email`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8de2e2e41b23c466793a67966d20bad67b1263cd/Documentation/git-send-email.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email))</sup> gets some optimization, some related to commits mentioned above.

See [commit 17530b2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17530b2ed2eac62706b8bbbcf93f62866f651ffd), [commit c95e3a3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c95e3a3f0b8107b5dc7eac9dfdb9e5238280c9fb), [commit 5a544a4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a544a4e11e2a08a813215c1b9cc80cc1555c7c2), [commit f4dc943](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f4dc9432fd287bde9100488943baf3c6a04d90d1), [commit 447ed29](https://github.com/git/git/commit/447ed29c0d414547914c23e92f8bb13fcf748f9b), [commit 4adbf38](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4adbf387bfd4b03b838282757e0bdf67e8f9fc8d), [commit fef381e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fef381e6dcbc328c4ccabaf4e8d4cdf19d1aba00), [commit 9264d29](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9264d29bf6da9e1789d71807dd72bbd4fb447887), [commit 2b110e9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2b110e9ba255120a2d78a5d2cccc842519e341f1), [commit 119974e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/119974e9e7f3569400aa1950529f69431534a617), [commit 671818a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/671818ab0b8206481d38054477059fee46db0ba3), [commit 879be43](https://github.com/git/git/commit/879be4319f70a2d6c65c3444a269bff671d182cd), [commit ecc4ee9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ecc4ee9cac60600f38542cebd940b4bd8b6497c8) (28 May 2021) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8de2e2e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8de2e2e41b23c466793a67966d20bad67b1263cd), 22 Jul 2021)</sup>

> ### [`send-email`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9264d29bf6da9e1789d71807dd72bbd4fb447887): lazily load config for a big speedup
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Reduce the time it takes [`git-send-email`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9264d29bf6da9e1789d71807dd72bbd4fb447887/Documentation/git-send-email.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email))</sup> to get to even the most trivial of tasks (such as serving up its "-h" output) by first listing config keys that exist, and only then only call e.g. "[`git config --bool`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9264d29bf6da9e1789d71807dd72bbd4fb447887/Documentation/git-config.txt#L202)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt---bool))</sup> on them if they do.
>
> Over a lot of runs this speeds the time to "`-h`" up for me from ~250ms to ~150ms, and the runtime of t9001-send-email.sh goes from ~25s to ~20s.
>
> This introduces a race condition where we'll do the "wrong" thing if a config key were to be inserted between us discovering the list and calling `read_config()`, i.e.
> we won't know about the racily added key.
> In theory this is a change in behavior, in practice it doesn't matter.
>
> The `config_regexp()` function being changed here was added in [dd84e52](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd84e528a34c3822e7ab0473a95e411665b37681) ("`git-send-email`: die if sendmail.* config is set", 2020-07-23, Git v2.29.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a00bda2b2fa5e6a8b224734cf72bb0601cd65b8a) listed in [batch #8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2befe97201e1f3175cce557866c5822793624b5a)) for use by git-send-email.
> So we can change its odd return value in the case where no values are found by git config".
> The difference in the `*.pm` code would matter if it was invoked in scalar context, but now it no longer is.

---

Note: Git 2.33 feature above broke `gitk`, which has been fixed with Git 2.34 (Q4 2021):

See [commit b996f84](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b996f84989f78c8f6d2429b5f0b9785e13f7af23) (06 Sep 2021) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 10de757](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10de757a09414a06739478c687ea6a24234c8ee8), 15 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`send-email`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b996f84989f78c8f6d2429b5f0b9785e13f7af23): fix a "first config key wins" regression in v2.33.0
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Eli Schwartz</sup>
> <sup>Tested-by: Eli Schwartz</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Fix a regression in my [c95e3a3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c95e3a3f0b8107b5dc7eac9dfdb9e5238280c9fb) ("`send-email`: move trivial config handling to Perl", 2021-05-28, Git v2.33.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8de2e2e41b23c466793a67966d20bad67b1263cd) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb27b338a3e71c7c4079fbac8aeae3f8fbb5c687)) where we'd pick the first config key out of multiple defined ones, instead of using the normal "last key wins" semantics of "[`git config --get`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b996f84989f78c8f6d2429b5f0b9785e13f7af23/Documentation/git-config.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config))</sup>".
>
> This broke e.g. cases where a `.git/config` would have a different `sendemail.smtpServer` than ~/.gitconfig.
> We'd pick the `~/.gitconfig` over `.git/config`, instead of preferring the repository-local version.
> The same would go for `/etc/gitconfig` etc.
>
> I.e.
> having any of these set in say `~/.gitconfig` and in-repo `.git/config` regressed in v2.33.0 to prefer the `--global` one over the --local.

Comment: @GanapathiBhat I have edited the answer: the sendemail config should be updated.

Comment: OK; I did follow the send-email config, tried same command and it ask for confirmation prior to sending(same as in my original trial); But, when I press 'y', it does not return for around couple of minutes, and then say Unable to `initialize SMTP....`; I have edited the question to add these details;

Comment: @GanapathiBhat Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: very sorry; I can check it but is there a quick way(command line preferred) to confirm this; I am using Ubuntu;

Comment: Thanks; It is not showing any proxy settings; But it looks(from `tcpdump -i eth0 |grep -i smtp`) that nothing goes out of my machine;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194371/discussion-between-ganapathi-bhat-and-vonc).

Comment: I was using wrong "smtpserver"; I contacted the IT person, got the correct "smtpserver" to be used, which fixed the issue; Thanks a lot for the help;

Comment: @GanapathiBhat Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: changing sendmail to sendemail solved the problem for me. Thanks