# Numerical result out of range while sending email using git

Tags: git, github, ubuntu-16.04

Facing error when sending e-mail using git:

`git send-email --to "abc.123@test.com"  --cc "def456@test.com" somefix.patch`

After this command, getting the following output:

`Failed to run command 'send-email': Numerical result out of range`

I even tried removing double quotes around the e-mails - didn't work.

```
$ git --version
git version 2.7.4
```

OS - ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Do you have the `git-email` package installed?  If so, what does `git config -l` produce (edit your question to include a text block)?

Answer (score 0):

Try first and [update Git itself](http://sudo%20add-apt-repository%20ppa:git-core/ppa%20sudo%20apt-get%20update%20sudo%20apt%20install%20git):

```
 Git:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install git
```

See if the issue persists with Git 2.25.1.

Make sure your [`sendemail` parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56421328/6309) are correct.